# Default Manager "Objects" is not working for me

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm very new in Python & Django and I'm following a tutorial but for some reason, a similar exercise I'm trying to do is not working for me.

I'm creating a simple views.py and a simple class MissingBusiness.
Trying to refer to the "objects" default manager for the model class is not recognized.
I want to use MissingBusiness.objects.all() to get all records from the database.
How to make objects to be recognized?

**This is my views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse     
from django.shortcuts import render    
from .models import MissingBusiness     

def indexRoot (request):    
    BusinessList = MissingBusiness.objects.all()  
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models    

class MissingBusiness(models.Model):    
    businessName = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    category = models.IntegerField()
```

**Seems the default manager "objects" is not recognized for some reason.

getting an error:**

```
AttributeError at /ManageMissingBusinesses/
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Request Method:
GET 

Request URL:
http://localhost:59564/ManageMissingBusinesses/ 

Django Version:
2.2.5 

Exception Type:
AttributeError 

Exception Value:
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Exception Location:
C:\Python\BankAccountUI\BankAccountUI\ManageMissingBusinesses\views.py in indexRoot, line 7 

Python Executable:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe 

Python Version:
3.6.3 

Python Path:
['C:\\Python\\BankAccountUI\\BankAccountUI',
 'C:\\Python\\BankAccountUI\\BankAccountUI',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual '
 'Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual '
 'Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:
Wed, 9 Oct 2019 19:32:12 +0000
```

Comment: You have something else - a function - called MissingBusiness.

Comment: As is, your code shouldn't throw this error.  Which means you are missing something.  As already pointed out, you probably have a function called `MissingBusiness` in your views or in your models that is overriding the model class.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, not sure I understand what is the problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know how I can make it any clearer. You have a function in your views.py file also called MissingBusiness. So when you do `MissingBusiness.objects.all()` you are referring to the funcdtion, not the model class.\

Comment: Got you. Thanks.